# How to change the gem5 ARM SVE vector length?

Tags: gem5

I'm doing an experiment to see which ARM SVE vector length would be the best for my chip design, or to help select which chip has the optimal vector length for my application.

How to change the vector length in a gem5 simulation to see how it affects workload performance?

Answer (score 0):

For SE:

```
se.py --param 'system.cpu[:].isa[:].sve_vl_se = 2'
```

For FS:

```
fs.py --param 'system.sve_vl = 2'
```

where the values are given in multiples of 128 bits, so `2` means length 256.

You can test this easily with the ADDVL instruction as [shown in this example](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/6936bd6ba996dee40f7cd826e5cf01ef39c2cabf/userland/arch/aarch64/sve_addvl.S).

The name of those parameters can be easily determined by looking at a `m5out/config.ini` generated from a previous run.

Note however that this value is architecturally visible, and so it might not be possible to checkpoint after Linux boot, and restore with a different vector length than the boot, to speed up experiments. This is likely true in general even though the kernel itself does not run vector instructions, because there is software control of the effective vector length. Maybe it is possible to set a big vector length on the simulator to start with and then tell Linux to reduce it somehow in software, but I'm not sure what's the API.

Tested in gem5 3126e84db773f64e46b1d02a9a27892bf6612d30.

Answer (score 0):

To change the vector length, one can use command line option:

`--arm-sve-vl=<vl in quadwords: one of {1, 2, 4, 8, 16}>`

where `vl` is a multiple of 128. So for a simulation of 512-bit SVE machine, one should use:

`--arm-sve-vl=4`

This works both for Syscall-Emulation mode and Full System mode.

If one wants to quickly explore the space of different vector lengths, one can also change it during the simulation (only in Full system mode). For example, to change the SVE length to 256, put the following line in your bootscript, before running the benchmark:

`echo 256 >/proc/sys/abi/sve_default_vector_length`

You can get more information on https://www.rico.cat/files/ICS18-gem5-sve-tutorial.pdf.